# Powerpivot how to sum value from tables (n:1:n)

Tags: dax, powerpivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvZyf.jpg)

Hello all, I'd like to pivot table:

Market  PROD_COD    sum(Value)

I have no idea how to write dax.
Thanks in advance

I've tried
CALCULATE(sumx(plus,plus[Value]),prod[PROD_COD]) but it dosent work.

Comment: Flip your relationship around for `prod` and `mkt_prod`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
TotalV:=
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(YM_Sales[Value]),
    TREATAS(VALUES(mkt_prod[PROD_COD]), 'YM_Sales'[PROD_COD])
  )
```